# how to deploy .mdf file

Tags: sql-server, mdf

I am trying to make an application, which uses a local .mdf database file (not attached to a sql server).
Visual Studio says I have to install SQL Server Express before doing that.
I was wondering how I can deploy the application to clients' box. Do they also need SQL Server Express installed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: mdb = MS Access / SQL Server uses .mdf/.ndf/.ldf - so what is it now??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They need SQL Server Express installed. Once installed, you need to attach the database file (.mdf) to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to attach it to the server. I just want it to stand alone. Does this require installation of sql express, since I don't want my clients to install that.

Comment: Yes. A .mdf file has to be attached to an instance of SQL Server to be usable. If this is not an option, investigate SQL Server Compact Edition. Files for this server have an .sdf extension. I do not know what programming language you are using, but if it is a flavor of .NET, SQL Server CE can be embedded within your application and does not require a stand-alone server.

Comment: If you want your databases to be self-contained and not require a server, use either MS Access (\*.mdb/\*.accdb) or SQLite databases. If you need your databases to be protected with usernames and passwords, go with Access.

Answer (score 4):

Don't deploy MDFs. Have your application use deployment scripts and run the scripts that create the database, as well as scripts that create all the objects in the database. The issue with deploying a binary (an .MDF) is that you won't be able to upgrade it. Come v. 1.1 of your application, you'll  face the dilema of how to deploy your *new* MDF, but preserver all the data your users saved in the *old* .MDF. This is not a trivial issue. Red Gate is trying to push its [contiguous integration solution](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-developer-bundle/learn-more/continuous-integration) which uses diff tools to generate maintenance/upgrade scripts. Microsoft is pushing the Database Project which works similarly based on diff comparison done by the [vsdbcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) tool. I'm  not a fan of diff based tools, they are prone to making bad decisions, I much much more prefer [explicit upgrade scripts](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Comment: You're right that tools can make poor decisions as they can't second guess user intent. At Red Gate we'll soon be adding a new feature into SQL Compare that allows the user to customize the migration script and save it to be reused in future migrations that span the same database versions. Contact david.atkinson at red-gate.com for more information.

Comment: Is there a reason not to deploy an mdf at initial install, and use scripts for upgrades thereafter?

Comment: You're dependent on the right versions then - with an initial script, that will work on whatever version the client is using (depending on any version specific features you've used, of course).

Answer (score 0):

in solution explorer right click on your project

then on new item

then select Serviced based database

create a database and use it